# How can I evaluate Javascript ES6 code at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I want to execute ES6 code at runtime using Node.js. Given a string of code:

```
const es6code = 'const square = (b) => { return b * b; }';
es6Eval(es6code)(5)
```

The `es6Eval` function would transpile es6 to es5 and evaluate the code at runtime.

How do I do this?

Comment: Given the `const` in your `const es6code`, you're running this code in an "ES6" (which is to say, ES2015+) environment. So...`const f = eval(es6code)` and then `f(5)` as necessary -- ***IF*** you trust the source of the code and are happy to run that code in your environment.

Comment: var fn = Function("alert('hello world')");
fn();

Comment: Since you're using Node.js which does support ES6 just well, why not use the native `eval` function?

Comment: My comment above isn't *quite* right for that `es6code`; I've posted an answer that is.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's get this out of the way: You **MUST TRUST THE SOURCE OF THAT CODE**. You're asking how to run arbitrary code from a string in your environment. If that code is malicious, bad things can happen. So you must trust the source of the code (e.g., whoever gave it to you).

Assuming you trust whomever you're getting the code from:

1. Given the `const` in your `const es6code`, you're running this code in an "ES6" (which is to say, ES2015+) environment. So...

   ```
   const f = new Function(es6code + "; return square;")();
   // Note ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^
   // And --------------------------------------------/
   ```

   then

   ```
   console.log(f(5)); // 25
   ```
2. If you need to transpile it first, use the [Node API for Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) to transform the code first:

   ```
   var code = require("babel-core").transform(es6code, options);
   ```

   ...and then do #1 on the result.